# Error in my MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is an error I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET belongs_to = 'kl', SET college = 'klnmhj' , SET works_a' at line 4

I'm not able to figure out how to deal with this error. Help please!

Comment: show us your complete statement

Comment: Without the full statement it is difficult to give you a full answer. But, have a look at you sql statement. locate the part where the error is mentions, debug from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give you a complete answer without the entire statement, but with the given code, I would say you should at least not repeat the SET keyword

```
SET belongs_to = 'kl', 
    college = 'klnmhj' , 
    works_a = 'something'
```

Comment: There's probably one more column being assigned *before* `belongs_to`, otherwise MySQL error message would point to the next `SET`.

Comment: Thanks, The problem was with the SET. Shouldn't have repeated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,etc
```